# Python Kivy - Извлечь координаты нарисованной окружности

Tags: python, kivy

В приложении Kivy на Python рисую окружность с помощью вот такой функции:

```
from kivy.graphics import Line

def draw_circle(r, canvas, x, y):
    canvas.clear()
    with canvas:
        Line(circle=(x, y, r))
```

Получаю вот такую окружность:

[image: Окружность в Kivy Python]
И у меня вот такой вопрос: могу ли я как-то извлечь все координаты точек, которые образуют окружность?

Еще я знаю, что окружность состоит из сегментов, тогда можно ли как-то извлечь номер сегмента, зная координату какой-то точки с окружности (а ещё лучше узнать угол наклона сегмента).

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то встроенной функции нет.
Но вы можете воспользоваться формулой 
(x1-x)**2 + (y1-y)**2 = r**2,
Где x, y - координаты центра
Все решения уравнения и будут точками окружности

Угол можно получить через sin

Comment: Спасибо. Но я эту формулу конечно же знаю. Дело в том, что я буду рисовать части окружностей, чтобы сделать выпуклую линзу. Вот так: [Пример того, что делает моя программа](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3xdi.png). Думал, что есть какой-то встроенный метод.